# Как поменять setkeycodes для "enter" и "ctrl+d"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Подскажите, как для этих клавиш поменять `setkeycodes`?

```
$ showkey -a

Нажимайте любые клавиши — работа программы завершается по Ctrl-D

^M   13 0015 0x0d
^D    4 0004 0x04 
$ sudo setkeycodes 0x04 13
[sudo] пароль для inikulin: 
KDSETKEYCODE: Недопустимый аргумент
не удалось установить скан-код 4 коду клавиши 13
```

Или может я аргументы пишу неправильные? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: вообще задача в том, чтобы showkey -a завершался не по нажатию комбинации ctrl+d, а по нажатию enter

Comment: Почему бы не просто пропатчить программу showkey?

Comment: @andreymal, а как это сделать?

Comment: Скачать исходники, заменить Ctrl+D на Enter, скомпилировать

Comment: @andreymal, тогда это не особо подходит мне, ибо я пишу сценарий на bash, и насколько я понимаю, данный сценарий не будет работать уже на другой машине

Comment: Всё же, похоже, про задачу вы что-то не договариваете)